# Given a sorted list of integers, square the elements and give the output in sorted order

Tags: python, loops, sorting

Can anybody help me with this. I don't know what am I doing wrong over here

```
list = [-9, -2, 0, 2, 3]
squared_list=[]


for element in list:
    squaring = list[element] * list[element]
    squared_list.append(squaring)

squared_list.sort()
print(squared_list)
```

Comment: what do you think `list[element]` is doing? what is the value of element?, just use `squared_list.append(element**2)`  Whole thing as a one-liner: `squared_list = sorted([e**2 for e in lst])`

Comment: You're probably confusing Python `for-in` loops - which iterate over values - with JavaScript `for-in` loops which iterate over indices.

Comment: `print(list[element])` will point your issue

Comment: don't use `list` as variable name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. "Can anybody help me with this. I don't know what am I doing wrong over here" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) that is appropriate for the site. If you "don't know what you are doing wrong", the first step is to find out why you think there is something wrong at all - is there an error message? is the output wrong? Next, try to find a specific cause for that. For example, what error message did you get? Where does it say the error occurred? What *were the values* of the variables that were involved in that code?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before applying them to your question. I have removed the [tag:dsa] tag which was incorrectly applied, even though the tag description clearly states that it relates to the DSA cryptographic primitive and not general data structures/algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `squaring = element * element` against `squaring = list[element] * list[element]` because for the first element, for example, you're consulting list[-9] and that index is out.